# writing the values of variables to file. the value is got changed automatically

Tags: bash

```
temp="This is the \\, example"
perl -pi -e "s/new.*/$temp/" tmp.txt
```

output:

```
cat tmp.txt
This is the \, example
```

In the above example the output should contain double `\`. but it contain only one `\`.
is there is any reason?

Answer (score 1):

Backslash is the escape character inside double quotes. Use a single quote to disable escaping.

It's also an escape character in `perl` regexp and replacement strings, so you need to double it to make it expand literally.

```
temp='This is the \\\\, example'
perl -pi -e "s/new.*/$temp/" tmp.txt
```

Comment: `sed 's/\\\\/\\\\\\\\/'`

Comment: Code in comments is unreadable. If you have a different problem, post a new question.

Answer (score 0):

temp= "new \\\\,"

cat tmp.txt
This is old Text

perl -pi -e "This.*/$temp/g" tmp.txt

cat tmp.txt
This is new\,Text

Still im getting same output after adding \\\\.

Comment: You're using double-quotes instead of single-quotes when you define the `temp` variable. As a result, the variable only has two backslashes, instead of four. Try printing the variable with `printf '%s\n' "$temp"`